# DataDog logger doesn't log INFORMATION level

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, .net-5, datadog

I have .NET 5 web app which is supposed to write logs to DataDog using Serilog Sink (Serilog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs v0.5.2). Here is my Program.cs:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.DatadogLogs("HERE IS MY API KEY", service: "myservice", configuration: new DatadogConfiguration() { Url = "https://http-intake.logs.us3.datadoghq.com" })
        .CreateLogger())
    {
        log.Debug("debug");
        log.Information("information");
        log.Verbose("verbose");
        log.Warning("warning");
        log.Error("error");
        log.Fatal("fatal");
    }

    using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

After running the app i can see all these logs in DataDog EXCEPT **Information** logs. So, i see only 5 messages instead of 6. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: So, you **do** see "debug" but _not_ "information" ? Is that correct? And it is _not_ a filter in the log analysis, right?

Comment: @Fildor correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason turned out to be on DataDog side. There was an indexation rule set up in our Logs Configuration that is telling to exclude 99% of all INFO logs (DataDog > Logs > Configuration > Indexes tab). Disabling this rule solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're setting the Serilog log event level but not the [Datadog level](https://github.com/DataDog/serilog-sinks-datadog-logs#support-configuration-options). Try this:

```
.WriteTo.DatadogLogs("HERE IS MY API KEY", 
        service: "myservice",
        logLevel: LogEventLevel.Information,
        configuration: new DatadogConfiguration() { 
            Url = "https://http-intake.logs.us3.datadoghq.com" }
    )
```

Comment: No, it didn't help. There is probably something wrong on the DataDog side because I was also trying to send these logs from my Ubuntu VM using `curl` command.

```
curl -s \
    -H "DD-API-KEY: $DataDogAPIKey" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "[{\"ddsource\":\"ubuntu\",\"service\":\"$DataDogAPIService\",\"message\":\"{\\\"timestamp\\\":\\\"$(date +%s%3N)\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"TEST\\\",\\\"MessageTemplate\\\":\\\"TEST\\\",\\\"level\\\":\\\"Debug\\\",\\\"Properties\\\":{}}\"}]" \
    -X POST \
    $DataDogAPI > /dev/null
```

Comment: And when level is set to Debug, then i can see my log in DataDog. But if change it to either Information or Info, then i cannot find it in DataDog